# I can't load my scss file while server side rendering in react 18

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

**REACT 18.2.0:**

Im facing challenges incorporating SCSS files into server-side rendering.
Im trying to load my scss file while server side rendering but it doesn't work
Can someone help?

My webpack:

```
(... imports)

module.exports = {
  entry: './server/index.js',
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('server-build'),
    filename: 'index.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      }
    ]
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals({ allowlist: /\.css$/ })]
};
```

My server.js:

```
(imports...)

app.use('/static/css', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'static', 'css')));

app.use('/*', (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        fs.readFile(path.resolve('./build/index.html'), 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
                return res.status(500).send("Some error happened")
            }
            return res.send(
                data.replace(
                    '<div id="root"></div>', 
                    `<div id="root">${renderToString(<App/>)}</div>`)
            )
        })

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
    }
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

What am I doing wrong?